# Main Reference + Appendix with "Other Sources"

Tags: bibliographies, subdividing

I need your help with references. I have 1 main reference section, and I want to include a second list of references as an appendix. For the main reference I use:

```
\newpage

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}

\bibliography{library}
```

The problem is that I don't know how to include the second list using a different bib file, and then calling the function `\nocite{*}` to show every sources inside the file.

I have the appendix part workout. I need your help to design the function to call the second bibliography, and that does't interfere with the main reference:

```
\newpage

\appendix

\section{Other Sources} \label{app:ReferencesB}
```

In addition, I will prefer that the word `References` is not shown after `Other Sources`.

Thank you so much!!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`multibib`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/multibib) package. Basically, you load the package and use \newcites for the bibliography in the appendix:

```
\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{Other Sources}
```

and then, at the point where you want this bibliography, you use

```
\appendix
\nocitesec{*}
\bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
\bibliographysec{otherbibtest}
```

A little complete example illustrating the general idea:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{bibtest.bib}
@article{TM83,
  author = "L\^e D{\~u}ng Trang and Zoghman Mebkhout",
   title = "Vari\'et\'es caract\'er\-istiques et vari\'et\'es polaires",
 journal = "C. R. Acad. Sc. Paris",
  volume = 296,
    year = 1983,
   pages = "129--132"}

@article{BMM94,
  author = "Jo{\"e}l Biran{\c c}on and Philippe Maisonobe and Michel Merle",
   title = "Localisation de syst\`emes diff\'erentiels, stratifications
            de {W}hitney et condition de {T}hom",
 journal = "Invent. Math.",
  volume = 117,
    year = 1994,
   pages = "531--550"}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{otherbibtest.bib}
@article{PP95,
  author = "Adam Parusi\'nski and Piotr Pragacz",
   title = "A formula for the {E}uler characteristic of singular hypersurfaces",
 journal = "J. Alg. Geom.",
  volume = 4,
    year = 1995,
   pages = "337-351"}

@article{Bry82,
  author = "Jean--Luc Brylinski",
   title = "({C}o)--{H}omologie d'intersection et faisceaux pervers",
 journal = "S\'eminaire Bourbaki",
  volume = 585,
    year = 1982,
   pages = "129--157"}

@article{Ken90x,
  author = "Gary Kennedy",
   title = "Specialization of {M}ac{P}herson's {C}hern classes",
 journal = "Math. Scand.",
  volume = 66,
    year = 1990,
   pages = "12--16"}

@article{Par88,
  author = "Adam Parusi\'nski",
   title = "A generalization of the {M}ilnor number",
 journal = "Math. Ann.",
  volume = 281,
    year = 1988,
   pages = "247--254"}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{sec}{Other Sources}

\begin{document}

\cite{BMM94,TM83}
\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{bibtest}
\appendix
\nocitesec{*}
\bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
\bibliographysec{otherbibtest}

\end{document}
```

The main bibliography:

[image]

The bibliography in the appendix:

[image]

Assuming your `.tex` document is called `mydoc.tex`, you need to process the document in the following way:

```
pdflatex mydoc
bibtex mydic
bibtex sec
pdflatex mydoc
pdflatex mydoc
```

Switching to [`biblatex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) for your bibliographies could be a choice here or in future documents. Using the features of `biblatex`, this kind of things are more easily done and your bibliographies will be better.

Comment: @IgnacioSala You're welcome! Don't forget that you can accept the answer (in case you consider it solved your problem) by clicking the checkmark to its left. In case of doubt, please see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852/3954).

Comment: My final question is how to process the file for the two different bibtex files. I only know how to run it by selecting bibtex and pressing the play bottom. I can't find a way for this specific arrangement that two files have to be run? I am using TeXworks for mac. Thanks for your support!

Comment: @IgnacioSala I do this processing using a terminal; there I run the commands (one at a time, of course) as they appear at the bottom of my answer..

Comment: I never run on terminal mode. Can you give me some recommendation on which software I can use? I am currently running TeXworks for mac. Thanks in advances!!!

Comment: @IgnacioSala some of the regulars here use arara (created by user Paulo Cereda). I haven't used it myself, but for what I've heard it seems a good tool and you can use it with TeXworks. Perhaps you could ask some of the fellows here in [`chat`](http://chat.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: What software do you use? Thanks

Comment: Hi @GonzaloMedina. Thank you for your answer. Everything is working great (that is, the references for either my main bibliography or the new bibliography for my appendix), but I am still receiving the warning "BibTeX: I didn't find a database entry for "..."" for the references present only in my appendix (i.e., my `\newcites{sec}{Other Sources}`). Also, is there a way to remove the heading "Other Sources"? I tried to keep it in blank such as `\newcites{sec}{}`, but it didn't work.