# Reference and Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex

I am trying to add two different sections to my document, a reference and a bibliography. The difference is basically this:

> A **reference list**, generally, contains only sources you have cited
> in-text in your assignment
>
> A **bibliography**, generally, is a list of all
> the sources you have used. This means, in addition to listing the
> sources you cited in-text, you also list resources that you read or
> referred to generate your ideas about the topic.

My question is, how to automatically move references that are not cited in-text to a new section called "Bibliography" and leave the cited in-text in one called "References"?

The code I am using to create the references:

```
\bibliographystyle{agsm}
\bibliography{references}
```

I am currently using BibTex and have a file .bib, which has these references:

```
@article{einstein,
    author =       "Albert Einstein",
    title =        "{Zur Elektrodynamik bewegter K{\"o}rper}. ({German})
        [{On} the electrodynamics of moving bodies]",
    journal =      "Annalen der Physik",
    volume =       "322",
    number =       "10",
    pages =        "891--921",
    year =         "1905",
    DOI =          "http://dx.doi.org/10.1002/andp.19053221004"
}
 
@book{latexcompanion,
    author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
    title     = "The \LaTeX\ Companion",
    year      = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
 
@misc{knuthwebsite,
    author    = "Donald Knuth",
    title     = "Knuth: Computers and Typesetting",
    url       = "http://www-cs-faculty.stanford.edu/\~{}uno/abcde.html"
}
```

The `latexcompanion` is not being cited in-text, so the end goal would be this:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please show us two bib entrys and the short code how you build your bibliography?

Comment: If `biblatex` is an alternative for you, you might be interested in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6977/105447 .

Comment: You could also add to your main document a second volume, which would include only your bibliography.

Comment: If you want to use `bibtex` please see the answer to question https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/126733/16550 Possible duplicate?